# Laravel Livewire Syncing Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a select2 multiple drop down menu that allows a user to select multiple locations to attach a new user to when they're creating the user.

I'm using `sync()` to store the array of locations after validating the data. I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`location_user`, CONSTRAINT
> `location_user_location_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`)
> REFERENCES `locations` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `location_user`
> (`id`, `location_id`, `user_id`) values (1001, 0, 3))

I understand the error, as I have a database background, what I don't understand is how to get Laravel to insert the right data. the insert statement is currently:

`(id, location_id, user_id) values (1001, 0, 3)`

but the values are in the wrong place or being mapped incorrectly. `1001` is the location ID, but is mapped to the `id`, presumably because I have `id` in my array, it's also pulling in 0 presumably because it's the array key, but that's not an actual value of anything.

I want it to ignore the id field on the pivot table and just insert `(location_id, user_id) values (1001, 3)`

Here's what my array looks like after validation:

[image]

Here's the code in my Livewire Component:

```
class Create extends Component
{
    public $user;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $role_id;
    public $roles;
    public $locations;

    protected $rules = [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:150'],
        ...
        'role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        'locations.*.id' => 'required|exists:locations,id'
    ]; 

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->locations = Auth::user()->locations;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.create');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        $newUserData = array_merge($validatedData, ['password' => Hash::make('temppassword')]);
        //dd($newUserData);
        $user = User::create($newUserData);
        $user->locations()->sync($validatedData['locations']);

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeModal');
        $this->emit('refreshUsers');
        $this->resetExcept('roles');
        $this->emit('userCreated');
    }
}
```

I've tried doing this in my livewire component:

`$user->locations()->sync(array_values($newUserData['locations']));`

but that produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$locations = Arr::flatten($newUserData['locations']);
$user->locations()->sync($locations);
```